# access to the index of item in *ngFor

Tags: angular

I have a loop in my html page. The code is:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items" style="display: inline;">    
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
           <a class="thumbnail" [routerLink]="['/single-picture/:comment', {comment:item.index} ]">
                <img  [src]=item.images.low_resolution.url>
           </a>
    </div>       
</li>
```

In the line `<a class="thumbnail" [routerLink]="['/single-picture/:comment', {comment:item.index} ]">`

**I want to pass the index of current item in the loop.**

How can i do it?

Comment: here is the syntax: <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">...</li>

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items;let i=index" style="display: inline;">      //<---added let i=index

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
       <a class="thumbnail" 
          [routerLink]="['/single-picture/:comment', {comment:i} ]">      //<-----changed this line 
           <img  [src]=item.images.low_resolution.url>
        </a>
    </div>  

</li>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the syntax from the documentation:

> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">...</li>
> <li template="ngFor let item of items; let i = index">...</li>
> <template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items" let-i="index"><li>...</li></template>
> ```

**Refer to the [documentation here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html)**

***For your case:***

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items;let i=index" style="display: inline;">    
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
           <a class="thumbnail" [routerLink]="['/single-picture/:comment', {comment:item.index} ]">
                <img  [src]=item.images.low_resolution.url>
           </a>
    </div>       
</li>
```