# Angular ngFor access index

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

How can I access index inside the ngFor?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ekze7q

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [access to the index of item in \*ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38911079/access-to-the-index-of-item-in-ngfor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add a * in ngFor and the var name is wrong

```
<p *ngFor="let i of Arr(count); let index = index">
  <button (click)="removeElement(index)">test</button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print the numbering using index try this, it will help you.

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of Array; let i = index">
 <li> {{i+1}}={{item.name}}</li> 
</ul>
```

For reference:
https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf